# Network: retrieve a list of latest posts

Tags: plugins, theme-development, multisite

I need to list all the latest x posts from the whole Network in my WordPress Network. 
I am already using the Sitewide Tags plugin to collect all posts in a separate blog, but I also need to list the latest posts elsewhere.

Most scripts and plugins I have been looking at only list one post from each blog, but I need to list the latest X posts, sorted by date, and allow several posts from each blog site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Sitewide Tags to populate one blog, then using the RSS feed from that blog to display the lastest posts wherever you need them?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think about that in the first place. Obviously the simpliest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I could write a code here but it's already well written elsewhere - there is a bunch of example but ready to use multisite plugins by [Brad Williams](http://strangework.com/) available to download from: [Code Download for Chapter 15 [zip]](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/22/04709162/DOWNLOAD/Chapter%2015%20Code.zip).
It's intended to accompany his [Professional Plugin Development Book](http://justintadlock.com/plugindevbook) but it's available for free download and could serve you well even without the book.

Especially these two plugins from the pack will be helpful:

- `boj-multisite-latest-network-posts.php`
- `boj-multisite-widget.php`

You could be able to use them straight away or make it suite your liking with just a few simple modifications.

The most important and helpful functions for your use case are:

- [switch_to_blog()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog), [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and  [restore_current_blog()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) for collecting the posts across the network.
- PHP's [usort()](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for sorting the collected posts by date.

*And don't hesitate to ask if any of these functions or techniques used in the plugins needs more explanation...*